# ECS services: loop over ECS cluster and scale down all tasks to 0

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to write a script thats stops all services in an existing cluster.
To accomplish this, ECS services must be scaled down to desired state of 0 tasks
So far, I managed to do this for a single service via a simple shell script
example:

```
 aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --service ${nameService} --task-definition ${taskDefinition} --desired-count 0
```

the problem I'm facing: how can I list all task's definitions:version linked to a giving service in a cluster and set the desired state to 0 in a loop

Answer (score 3):

1. **List services:**

   ```
   aws ecs list-services --cluster ${ecsClusterName}
   ```
2. **Write services in a file:**

   ```
   aws ecs list-services --cluster ${ecsClusterName} | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | rev | awk -F'/' '{print $1}' | rev | grep -v serviceArns > services.txt
   ```
3. **Scale down:**

   ```
   for service in $(cat services.txt); do aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --service "$service" --desired-count 0 --no-cli-pager > /dev/null; done
   ```